# 405 http method get is not supported by this url

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee

I have written a servlet for approval of leaves. In this servlet I have also written code to send a mail. Due to this, it shows HTTP 405 error. If I remove the code which sends a mail, then it does not show the error, but I need the mail code.

```
package mis;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.jdo.PersistenceManager;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import javax.jdo.Query;
import com.google.appengine.api.users.UserService;
import com.google.appengine.api.users.UserServiceFactory;

public class approve extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    throws IOException {

        try{



             HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);        

            PersistenceManager pm1 = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
         Query query1 = pm1.newQuery(Leave_bal.class);
         query1.setFilter("emp_Id == emp");
         query1.declareParameters("String emp");
         List<Leave_bal> results1 = (List<Leave_bal>)query1.execute(session.getAttribute("emp_Id").toString());

         String plan="";
         String unplan="";

         String planleave_result="" ;
         String unplanleave_result="";


         for (Leave_bal e : results1) 
         {
          plan=e.getplan_leave();
          resp.getWriter().println("Planned_Leave"+plan);

          unplan=e.getunplan_leave();
          resp.getWriter().println("Unplanned:"+unplan);
         }

        int plan_leave=Integer.parseInt(plan);
         int unplan_leave=Integer.parseInt(unplan);


       String ID=req.getParameter("id");
        resp.getWriter().println(ID);
        PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
        Query query = pm.newQuery(Leave_detail.class);
     query.setFilter("id == ID");
     query.declareParameters("String ID");       
     List<Leave_detail> results = (List<Leave_detail>)query.execute(ID);

     String plan_detail="";


     String duration="";
     for (Leave_detail e : results) 
     {
     plan_detail=e.getLeave_Type();
     duration=e.getdurtn();
     //f=e.getfrom();
    //t=e.getto();
     }

     resp.getWriter().println("duration "+duration);
     resp.getWriter().println("Planned_selected "+plan_detail);


         int duration_integer=Integer.parseInt(duration);
         resp.getWriter().println("duration "+duration_integer);


        //String duration=req.getParameter("date");
       // resp.getWriter().println("diffrence:"+duration);
        //int workingdays=Integer.parseInt(duration);                                            

        //String Leave = req.getParameter("a"); 
       // resp.getWriter().println("planned:"+Leave);

        if(plan_detail.equals("UNPLAN"))
        {                           
            unplan_leave=unplan_leave-duration_integer;
            unplanleave_result=String.valueOf(unplan_leave);
            planleave_result=plan;
        resp.getWriter().println("Planned After Change"+unplanleave_result);
            //st="Applied";

        }
        if(plan_detail.equals("PLAN"))
        {
            plan_leave= plan_leave-duration_integer;
            planleave_result=String.valueOf(plan_leave);
         resp.getWriter().println("Planned After Change"+planleave_result);
             unplanleave_result=unplan;

        }

        if(plan_detail.equals("LWP"))
        {
            plan_leave= plan_leave-duration_integer;
            planleave_result=String.valueOf(plan_leave);
             resp.getWriter().println("Planned After Change"+planleave_result);
             unplanleave_result=unplan;

        }

        if(plan_detail.equals("Onduty"))
        {
            planleave_result=plan;
             unplanleave_result=unplan;

        }




        Leave_detail status_update = pm.getObjectById(Leave_detail.class,ID);
        status_update.setstatus("Approved");
        pm.makePersistent(status_update); 

         Leave_bal ed1=new Leave_bal(session.getAttribute("emp_Id").toString(),planleave_result,unplanleave_result);

         pm.makePersistent(ed1);



//code for mail

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletConfig ( ) .getServletContext ().getRequestDispatcher("/MailServiceapply");         
         dispatcher.forward (req, resp) ;   

    pm.close();
    }
          catch(Exception a )
            {
                 resp.getWriter().println(a .getMessage());
            } finally{

            }
            resp.sendRedirect("hr.jsp#LMS");        
        }
}
```

Comment: can you please post the error message you are getting

Answer (score 1):

[This thread](http://www.java-forums.org/java-servlet/12405-http-status-405-http-method-get-not-supported-url.html) on Java Forums provides some hints for this error, like

- HTML form invokes POST operation and servlet doesn't implement `doPost` ([direct link](http://www.java-forums.org/java-servlet/12405-http-status-405-http-method-get-not-supported-url.html#post83870))
- Inital HTML form not declared in `web.xml` file (or misspelled) ([direct link](http://www.java-forums.org/java-servlet/12405-http-status-405-http-method-get-not-supported-url.html#post82123))

Comment: For me I didn't have the FULLY qualified package name before the class name in the web.xml file. Hopefully this helps someone else!

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of this servlet you're forwarding the request to another servlet:

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/MailServiceapply");
dispatcher.forward(req, resp);
```

This is not only a poor approach, certainly because you've written data to the HTTP response before in the servlet and you thus risk `IllegalStateException` (writing to the response should take place in a JSP), but doing so also requires that the servlet in question also implements `doGet()`. The error which you're facing suggests that this mail service servlet has only the `doPost()` implemented.

You need to add a `doGet()` method to the mail service servlet and use `RequestDispatcher#include()` to invoke it.

```
dispatcher.include(req, resp);
```

Needless to say that this is still a poor approach. You'd rather like to refactor the mail code logic into a standalone Java class which you then import and invoke in both servlets and put all the presentation logic in a JSP.